# Matlab: adding a third variable to custom data tips in a 2D plot

Tags: matlab, plot, datatip

I am using Matlab R2020b and I would like to display additional info when hovering the cursor over a data point in a 2D plot. I have values of angle and radius for a polarplot. Each data point is associated with a time. I create the plot similar to this:

```
t = linspace(0, 1, 100);
phi = 2*pi*t;
r = t.^2+1;

h = figure;
polarplot(phi, r, '-sb');

dcm = datacursormode(h);
datacursormode on;
set(dcm, 'updatefcn', @myfunction);


function output_txt = myfunction(obj,event_obj)
% Display data cursor position in a data tip
% obj          Currently not used
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data tip text, returned as a character vector or a cell array of character vectors

pos = event_obj.Position;


%********* Define the content of the data tip here *********%

% Display the x and y values:
output_txt = {['\phi: ' num2str(pos(1)*180/pi) '°'],...
    ['r: ' num2str(pos(2))]};
%***********************************************************%

% If there is a z value, display it:
if length(pos) > 2
    output_txt{end+1} = ['Z',formatValue(pos(3),event_obj)];
end

%***********************************************************%

end
```

Ideally, I would like to have a triplet of (angle, radius, time) dispayed for any data point that I select. The information about custom data tips does not tell me how I can add values of another variable (time), only when using a 3D plot such as plot3.

Do you know any solution to this problem?

Comment: Where is your code to create the custom datatip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have the time as a third value in your `polarplot` when selecting data points, and to do this you can add the time (variable `t`) to the `ZData` property of the `polarplot`.

To do this you want to use a handler for the polarplot axes, i.e. `hax = polarplot(phi, r, '-sb');` so that you can put the time as ZData: `hax.ZData = t;`. When you've done this, the variable `pos` in `myfunction` will have a length of 3 instead of 2 so your `if`-statement will be executed.

Your updated code should look something like this:

```
t = linspace(0, 1, 100);
phi = 2*pi*t;
r = t.^2+1;

h = figure;
hax = polarplot(phi, r, '-sb');   % New code
hax.ZData = t;                    % New code

dcm = datacursormode(h);
datacursormode on;
set(dcm, 'updatefcn', @myfunction);


function output_txt = myfunction(obj,event_obj)
% Display data cursor position in a data tip
% obj          Currently not used
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data tip text, returned as a character vector or a cell array of character vectors

  pos = event_obj.Position;


  %********* Define the content of the data tip here *********%

  % Display the x and y values:
  output_txt = {['\phi: ' num2str(pos(1)*180/pi) '°'],...
      ['r: ' num2str(pos(2))]};
  %***********************************************************%

  % If there is a z value, display it:
  if length(pos) > 2
      output_txt{end+1} = ['Z',formatValue(pos(3),event_obj)];
  end

  %***********************************************************%

end
```

Let me know if it doesn't work :) Good luck!